# Wordpress AJAX Login Not Redirecting After Successful Login

Tags: ajax, wordpress, redirect, authentication

I have implemented the AJAX based log in functionality in my WP site as follows:

`functions.php`

```
function ajax_login_init(){

    wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'redirecturl' => home_url(),
        'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
    ));

    // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
}

// Execute the action only if the user isn't logged in
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
}

function ajax_login(){

    // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

    // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
    $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $info['remember'] = true;

    $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
    }

    die();
}
```

`ajax-login-script.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

    // Perform AJAX login on form submit
    jQuery('form#login_form').on('submit', function(e){
        jQuery('form#login_form p.login-status').show().text(ajax_login_object.loadingmessage);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
            data: { 
                'action': 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                'username': jQuery('form#login_form #txtEmail').val(), 
                'password': jQuery('form#login_form #txtPassword').val(), 
                'security': jQuery('form#login_form #security').val() },
            success: function(data){
                jQuery('form#login_form p.login-status').text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true){
                    document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Now when I enter wrong credentials in my login popup, it successfully shows me the waiting message, and then error `Wrong username or password.`. But when I use correct credentials and press sign in, then it silently logs me in but never refreshes the page (actually it does try to refresh the page in the background, but since it is an ajax request, i can only see the refresh in `console` tab).

I want the ajax to refresh my current page from which the request has been sent.

I assume that the culprit could be this snippet:

```
$user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
            echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
        }
```

When `$user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );` is called, it actually logs the user in and redirects the page (within AJAX), and never executes code further. Hence, I don't get the JSON encoded data in my AJAX success function (which is where I am actually trying to redirect the page using JavaScript).

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try reversing the order `if ( !is_wp_error($user_signon) )` and also inverse the 2 echo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did it another way. Used `wp_check_password`, `wp_set_current_user` and `wp_set_auth_cookie` functions to achieve the same goal.

```
function ajax_login(){

    // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

    // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
    $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $_POST['email'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $info['remember'] = true;

    $userdata = get_user_by('login', $info['user_login']);
    $result = wp_check_password($info['user_password'], $userdata->data->user_pass, $userdata->data->ID);

    if ( $result ) {

        auto_login( $userdata );
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));

    } else {

        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));

    }

    die();

}

function auto_login( $user ) {

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {

        $user_id = $user->data->ID;
        $user_login = $user->data->user_login;

        wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user_login );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="well form-inline" id="login">
    <div id="message"></div>
    <div id="loading" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="rowmargin">
        <h4>Login</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="rowmargin">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="loginUsername" class="input-medium" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="loginPassword" class="input-medium" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="loginButton"><i class="icon-check icon-white"></i> Login</a>
</form>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
    jQuery('#loading').hide();
    jQuery("#loginButton").click(function() {   
        jQuery('#message').hide().html('');
        jQuery('#loading').hide();
        var input_data = jQuery('#login').serialize();
        var logUser = jQuery('#loginUsername').val();
        var logPass = jQuery('#loginPassword').val();

        if(logUser == '' && logPass != ''){ jQuery('#message').show().html('Your Username is empty!'); return false; }
        if(logPass == '' && logUser != ''){ jQuery('#message').show().html('Your Password is empty!'); return false; }
        if(logUser == '' && logPass == ''){ jQuery('#message').show().html('Your Username and Password is empty!'); return false; } 

        jQuery('#loading').show();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php','login_post'); ?>",
            data: input_data,
            success: function(msg) {                                    
                // login success. redirect users to some page.
                jQuery(location).attr('href', '<?php echo home_url( '/thank-you/' ); ?>');

            },
            error: function(msg) {  
                // login error.                 
                jQuery('#message').show();
                jQuery('#message').html("<?php _e('Your login  is not correct. Please try again.'); ?>");
                jQuery('#loading').hide();
            }

        }); 
        return false;
    });
});
```